# I have set two themes on WordPress, So how i can set header and footer on both

Tags: header

Actually i have recently setup 2 theme in my wordpress.
But in one theme my Custom Header and footer is visible and at another theme is not visible, here visible there is visible something different or might be default.

I want to solve this problem, i want to add those header and footer on my both theme.